# Understanding a specific scala class extension construct

Tags: scala

Hi I am trying to understand the following construct in scala:

```
sealed abstract class Weekday( val name: String,
                               val abbreviation: String,
                               val isWorkDay: Boolean)

case object Monday extends Weekday("Monday", "Mo.", true)
```

The sealed here is not important, example was taken from the famous blog of enumeratum which i have been using successfully but without understanding that fundamental construct above

What is

```
extends Weekday("Monday", "Mo.", true)
```

is that default values?

Or is it that one can just pass any value to an extends class constructor ? (it does not have to be the "usual" parameters of the constructor of the extending class)

I'm just looking for the definition of what is happening here.

Comment: _"I'm just looking for the definition of what is happening here"_, **Inheritance**? - Or _"is it that one can pass a value to an extends class constructor"_ you not only can, you **MUST** call the superclass constructor when constructing a subclass; and it has to be the first thing you do, **Scala** syntax just force you to do that whereas in **Java** you have to remember it _(or the compiler will automatically add a call to the empty constructor, which may lead to subtle bugs like NPEs)_ - _"it does not have to be the "usual" parameters of the constructor of the extending class"_ WDYM?

Comment: Sorry i did not express myself properly. The answer belows clarifies it all with `new Weekday("Monday", "Mo.", true) {}` . I always used inheritance more like class B(name: String) extends class A(name). Hence always thought the parameter must come from the constructor of the "extending class".

Comment: Also to be fair, I never do class inheritance in scala. always work with trait.

Comment: Ah, yeah you can always just use a constant values or even call another function _(not of the same class)_ and pass the result to the argument. - Constructors are _"technically"_ just another method (with a lot of disclaimers). - _"Also to be fair, I never do class inheritance in scala"._ same; however **Scala 3** will allow traits to have constructor parameters which will be great :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is that default values?

No, you could pass any values to `Weekday`'s constructor. It is similar to

```
lazy val Monday = new Weekday("Monday", "Mo.", true) {}
```

however by using `case object` you automatically get synthesised methods of `Product` and nice hashing. Defaults to `Weekday` constructor

```
sealed abstract class Weekday(
  val name: String = "Monday",
  val abbreviation: String = "Mon",
  val isWorkDay: Boolean = false
)
```

could still be overriden

```
case object Tuesday extends Weekday("Tueasday", "Tue", false)
```